# Get the currently executing TRIGGER_NAME in Job execute method

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

i am new to Quartz , i have populated the database with my job details , and triggers .What i want to do is get the currently executing trigger's TRIGGER_NAME value in the Job's execution .How do i do this ? I want to use the trigger name to search my database . THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is available in the context.

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Execute method for job {0} in group {1} called at {2}", context.JobDetail.Key.Name, context.JobDetail.Key.Group, DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine("Trigger {0} in group {1} was fired", context.Trigger.Key.Name, context.Trigger.Key.Group);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call

```
scheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs()
```

to get a list of JobExecutionContext objects. These contain references to the jobs and their triggers.

Comment: Please can you provide a code sample , thanks . I want to obtain the name of the current TRIGGER .